# Rust equivalent for C++ code to demonstrate protection against UAF

Tags: rust

I am trying to understand how Rust's lifetime annotations help catch use-after-free (UAF) issues without compromising on functionality. Here is the code I have :

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Foo {
    data: usize,
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn begin_foo(&self) {
        println!("Begin Foo");
    }

    pub fn end_foo(&self) {
        println!("End Foo");
    }
}

struct Bar {
    foo: Option<Foo>,
}

impl Bar {
    pub fn new(foo: Foo) -> Self {
        Bar {
            foo : Some(foo),
        }
    }

    pub fn get_foo(&self) -> Option<& Foo>
    {
        match &self.foo {
            Some(foo) => return Some(&foo),
            None => return None,
        }
    }
}

struct FooBar<'a> {
    bar : Option<Rc<Bar>>,
    foo : Option<&'a Foo>,
}

impl<'a> FooBar<'a> {
    pub fn new(bar : Option<Rc<Bar>>) -> Self {
        FooBar {
            bar : bar,
            foo : None,
        }
    }

    pub fn update_foo_1(&'a mut self)
    {
        if let Some(b) = &self.bar {
            self.foo = b.get_foo();
        }
    }

    // ERROR1
    /*
    pub fn update_foo_2(&mut self)
    {
        if let Some(b) = &self.bar {
            self.foo = b.get_foo();
        }
    }
    */

    pub fn invalidate_bar_1(&mut self) {
        self.bar.take();
    }

    // Inorder to drop the RC, we have to pass self and not &self, which consumes the object.
    pub fn invalidate_bar_2(self) {
        if let Some(bar) = &self.bar {
            println!("Strong ref count = {}", Rc::strong_count(bar));
            drop(self.bar.unwrap());
        }
    }

    pub fn use_foo(&self) {
        match self.foo {
            Some(foo) => println!("Foo.data = {}", foo.data),
            None => println!("Foo is None"),
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    
    #[test]
    fn works()
    {
        println!("Works...");
        let foo = Foo {data : 42};
        let bar = Bar::new(foo);

        let bar_rc = Rc::new(bar);
        assert_eq!(1, Rc::strong_count(&bar_rc));

        let mut foo_bar: FooBar = FooBar::new(Some(bar_rc));
        
        foo_bar.update_foo_1();
        foo_bar.use_foo();
        foo_bar.invalidate_bar_1();
        println!("Exiting works()...");
    }

    #[test]
    fn fails()
    {
        println!("Fails...");
        let foo = Foo {data : 42};
        let bar = Bar::new(foo);

        let bar_rc = Rc::new(bar);
        assert_eq!(1, Rc::strong_count(&bar_rc));

        let mut foo_bar: FooBar = FooBar::new(Some(bar_rc));
        
        foo_bar.update_foo_1();
        foo_bar.invalidate_bar_1();
        foo_bar.use_foo();
        println!("Exiting fails()...");
    }
}
```

The requirement is that `FooBar` holds `Bar` but also a reference to `Foo` to avoid calling `Bar::get_foo()` multiple times. `FooBar::invalidate_bar_*()` invalidates `Bar` leaving the reference `Foo` dangling.

Given the above requirement, the following sequence of calls should be valid :

```
foobar.update_foo();
foobar.use_foo();
foobar.invalidate_foo();
```

The following is an invalid sequence of calls and must be caught at compile-time :

```
foobar.update_foo();
foobar.invalidate_foo();
foobar.use_foo();
```

But this doesn't quite happen with my code above. The challenges that I am facing are:

1. In `FooBar::update_foo_1()` I am forced to annotate `self` with lifetime `&'a`. Otherwise I get the following error :

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:52:26
   |
52 |         if let Some(b) = &self.bar {
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 50:5...
  --> src/lib.rs:50:5
   |
50 | /     pub fn update_foo_1(& mut self)
51 | |     {
52 | |         if let Some(b) = &self.bar {
53 | |             self.foo = b.get_foo();
54 | |         }
55 | |     }
   | |_____^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:52:26
   |
52 |         if let Some(b) = &self.bar {
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 42:6...
  --> src/lib.rs:42:6
   |
42 | impl<'a> FooBar<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/lib.rs:53:24
   |
53 |             self.foo = b.get_foo();
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `std::option::Option<&'a Foo>`
              found `std::option::Option<&Foo>`
```

2. When I use the `&'a` to resolve the above error, I cannot make any other calls that require exclusive reference to `self` in the same scope :

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `foo_bar` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
   --> src/lib.rs:104:9
    |
103 |         foo_bar.update_foo_1();
    |         ------- mutable borrow occurs here
104 |         foo_bar.use_foo();
    |         ^^^^^^^
    |         |
    |         immutable borrow occurs here
    |         mutable borrow later used here
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is, how do I define `FooBar::update_foo_1, FooBar::invalidate_foo` in such a way that UAF issue is caught at compile time, i.e, allow to make the valid sequence of calls defined above but not the invalid sequence.

Comment: You never call drop ie `invalidate_bar_2`. Is this intended? The `take` also never drops `self.foo`, which would be necessary to make the whole thing blow up as intended.
It is super distracting that you call `foo` something which has no data and `Foo` the data. Maybe more meaningful names could help you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, doing the checks you want at compile time requires type classes, which Rust doesn't have, so the checks can only be done at runtime (eg. with `Option`). Or you need to change `invalidate_foo` so that it destroys the `FooBar` and returns just the `Bar`: `fn invalidate_foo (self) -> Bar { self.bar }`.

Comment: @jmb traits and typeclasses are analogous, maybe you're thinking of typestates? Or do you mean *higher-kinded types*? That's somewhat orthogonal. Haskell has higher-order types and rust doesn't, independent of what little differences there are between rust's traits and haskell's typeclasses.

Comment: @Masklinn, sorry yes I meant typestates

Comment: @Jay-Pi, `invalidate_bar_2` is another attempt at making this work. It consumes `self`, so we won't be able to refer to `FooBar` object after the call. This is useful if I am able to resolve the above two errors. sorry if the naming convention is distracting. Perhaps I should give `Option<Foo>` a different name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling this, you are making FooBar a self referential struct which is hard to define in safe rust.

```rust
    pub fn update_foo_1(&'a mut self)
    {
        if let Some(b) = &self.bar {
            self.foo = b.get_foo();
        }
    }
```

The compiler gives the error correctly here:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `foo_bar` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
   --> src/lib.rs:104:9
    |
103 |         foo_bar.update_foo_1();
    |         ------- mutable borrow occurs here
104 |         foo_bar.use_foo();
    |         ^^^^^^^
    |         |
    |         immutable borrow occurs here
    |         mutable borrow later used here
```

because if it did allow any immutable borrows after the update call, it would mean that there is no mutable borrow at that point, which also means that you can do mutable borrows after that.

What happens if the `bar` field's strong count was 1 and you did this:

```rust
drop(foo_bar.bar.take());
```

You'd have a dangling reference in the `foo` field of `FooBar`, which Rust forbids.

Comment: The reason I end up with self-referential struct is the error #1. If I define `update_foo_1(&mut self)` I get the error `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements`. TBH, I don't quite understand why. I was able to resolve it by making it self referential. If there is a better way to do this I would prefer that.

Comment: The code I had before making it self referential :
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0fd2ce882bead194741c7e243c1ce97a

Comment: It is still self referential. You want to store a reference to data from `bar` field into `foo` field. So, it has to live as long as `self` to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

> Rust's lifetime annotations help catch use-after-free (UAF) issues without compromising on functionality.

Rust's lifetime annotations don't "catch" anything. What they do is tell the compiler about things it may not be able to infer (namely how long borrows span).

What "catches" UAF issues is the affine type system, that is, after a *move* (aka taking something by value unless it's `Copy`), the source is inaccessible, and you can't move a structure which are active users (aka for which there are active references, all borrows must end before a structure is moved).

You're not using moves anywhere, so your `FooBar` object is guaranteed to always be valid.

As for the update_foo_1 issue, I think it's a logical consequence of what you're telling rust:

```rust
    pub fn update_foo_1(&'a mut self)
```

means that method is creating a borrow which lasts all of `'a`.

`'a` is a parameter to the structure so it needs to "outlive" the structure itself, and you're saying that you're exclusively borrowing the structure for that lifetime, which means `'a` is exactly the same lifetime as the structure (which makes sense since what you're borrowing is part of the structure) and the only thing you've done is statically locked yourself out of using said structure.

Expressing graphs (/ self-referential structures) is difficult to do in Rust, and that's exactly what you're trying to do here, but more fundamentally your entire endeavour seems misguided and based on misunderstandings.

Comment: I was a little loose with the terminology but I get what you are saying about lifetime annotations. I also understand why the compiler is complaining about borrowing self for `'a`. The ask is, how do I define `update_foo` to not run into these issues. The functionality I seek is IMO commonplace. Instead of calling another function each time we need a reference to something, we can store it. But this is also how we end up with dangling references. I would expect Rust to catch this at compile time. Do correct me if that is misguided.

Comment: Rust does catch it by essentially making it impossible, or requiring the use of runtime checks (e.g. Rc and weakrefs, if you make `Bar::foo` an `Option<Rc<Foo>>` and `FooBar::foo` a `Weak<Foo>` then it works but it's not zero-cost). Again, Rust plain and simply makes graphs (which self-referential data structures are) difficult to work with, there really are no good tools to make them statically safe, and so you either pay at runtime, or build dedicated data-structures using unsafe.